# Accurate count of Specific Item entry

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, date-time, sharepoint-views

Ultimately my goal is to get an accurate count of how many tickets were created with in the last 30 days using a created view.

I have four Date columns:

Create date | Start Date | Close Date | Today

I am attempting to create a view that gives me a count of tickets opened with in the last 30 days but I'm having trouble with the syntax in the view. Taking create date and today date and subtracting 30.

I'm not sure how to get the proper calculation to give me a proper count or if I'm even using the right information.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I below is how i have set up the calculation in the view but its still not working properly

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Modify the view and add a filter condition by selecting "Show items only when the following is true" and select the Create date column to show values equal to [Today]-30

Comment: I've updated the ticket with a screen shot of my view calculation but it didn't return the desired data. is there a data point I'm missing?

Comment: The field only shows 1 in the count.

Comment: I assume the "Create date" is the document created date or if not try the "created" field which is the ootb metadata field for the items.

Comment: Create Date is a date column i made to have users enter the date an item was submitted. I created this column because the create day many not be the say day they enter in the item.